# How to call one file functions in other files in custom module?

Tags: 7

I have created custom module in Drupal 7.

I want to create one file and in this file I want to create all functions that I need to use in this module. I want to call these functions in .module file. So for this what file and how can I use these functions?

Answer (score 1):

It's PHP, so you use `require` or `include` to include functions from other files.

Drupal's wrapper around those is [`module_load_include`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x). Examples from the docs:

```
// Load node.admin.inc from the node module.
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.admin');
// Load content_types.inc from the node module.
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'content_types');
```

Only use this function inside another function, not in global scope. If you need to unconditionally depend on a separate file for a whole module, just use `require_once` or whatever makes most sense for your use case.

Comment: I am creating custom module and want to use all function in .module file . and I have one file in module where I created all functioans.

Comment: I know, that's what your question says. This is the answer to that question